# Arraylist parcelable data to work in list fragment for viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

In my mainactivity , I have a gridview, when I am selecting an image of the grid, I am displaying the selected image on another activity.

in the another activity I have Listfragment so I can use view pager , its working fine for List < fragment> but I am getting from the other activity Listitem which is parcelable

I am recveing from mainactivity-gridview listiem which is parceable

```
 ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList = Bundle.getParcelableArraylist("person_List);
```

However in the another activity I am using list fragment

```
  List<Fragment> flist = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
```

My question how to add the parcable data into the list fragment so i can use the viewpager ?

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState);
   {
   super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity);
   List<Fragment> fragments=getFragments();

   Bundle bundle =getIntent().getextras();
  //I want the below arraylist to be added to fragment.. how to do that?
   ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList = Bundle.getParcelableArraylist("person_List");
   for (listitem person : personArrayList ){
  Log.i("Activity",String.valueof(person.url));
   }

 pageAdapter = new PageAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
 ViewPager pager= (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
 pager.setAdapter(pageadapter);
 }
// here I am adding the content for the fragments, how to add instead the content of the parcalble ?
private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
  List<Fragment> flist = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
 flist = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

 flist.add(MyFragment.newInstance("frag1");
 flist.add(MyFragment.newInstance("frag2");
 flist.add(MyFragment.newInstance("frag3");
 return flist;
 }

 class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  private List<Fragment> fragments;
  public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
  }
  @Override 
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
  }
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
  }
}
```

Comment: make your question more clear

Comment: @VivekMishra I tried my best to make it clear , I am receiving from main_activity a parcable arraylist okay ? this arraylist contain information of the grid view. I want to add this array list in the List<fragment> what I am doing now I am adding in the list `MyFragment.newInstance("frag1");` what I want is to replace "frag1" and add the data of the parcable array list .. did you understand me now ?

Comment: What I get from this is that onGridView click you get data of that position and display it another fragment??

Comment: @VivekMishra yes correct. I am getting the position of the gridview through parcable, `ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList = Bundle.getParcelableArraylist("person_List);` my question how to add those in the fragment list ? `List<Fragment> flist = new ArrayList<Fragment>();`

Comment: Is creatig a fragment list required?? Means can't you show one fragment at a time

Comment: @VivekMishra I am new to viewpager and fragment all I want is I am able to swipe the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99937/discussion-between-vivek-mishra-and-moudiz).